# Coordinates for kinect region on sdk 2.0

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect

I am working with kinect sdk 2.0 in visual studio 2013, C#. In that I develop the project of `using gesture as mouse` by using kinect region I done the operation of `press`, `drag` the button like this. But I want to sink the mouse with kinect region. So first I want to find coordinates for both.
How do find kinect region coordinates in kinect sdk 2.0? how to display?